# dynamic jpql returns collection but how to assign it to datatable?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa, primefaces

I have a dynamic jpql as follows:

```
public Collection getOrderReportByUserName(String userName, Integer scripID, String orderStatus, String orderType) 
{     

    String strQuery = null;

        Collection<TradeStock> ts = em.createQuery("Select t from TradeStock t where t.userName.userName = :userName").setParameter("userName",userName).getResultList();
        if(ts.isEmpty())
        {
            strQuery = "Select o from OrderStock o where o.userName.userName = :userName ";
        }
        else
        {
            strQuery = "Select o,t from OrderStock o,TradeStock t where o.userName.userName = :userName and t.userName.userName = :userName";
        }   

    Collection c = em.createQuery(strQuery).setParameter("userName",userName).getResultList();
    return c;  
}
```

bean code:

```
public collection getOrderReport()
    {

        collOrder=  getOrderReportByUserName(uname,scripID,orderStatus,orderType);

    }
```

xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="dt" var="order" widgetVar="scripTab" 
                     emptyMessage="No scrip found with given criteria" binding="#{stockOrderBean.dt}" 
                     value="#{stockOrderBean. collOrder}"
                 >

        <p:column>

            <f:facet name="header">
                Scrip Symbol
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{order.get(0)}"/> ?? how to assign it?
        </p:column>......
```

here when I debugged it I found that 'c' contains the returned collection, but now how do I assign it to a datatable? the collection returned contains objects of 2 tables- 'tradeStock' and 'orderStock'- so how do I use it in primefaces datatable?

**Edited:**
i want to display fields from two different classes - some fields from OrderStock and some fields from TradeStock which are joined by common field called 'OrderID'.. Is this possible?? If not then what can be the alternative solution??

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*Note: I recommend reading some very basics on Java development. There are some major flaws in your code.*</sub>

But as to your concrete problem:

If you have a method `getOrderReport()` in a bean called `StockOrderBean` you have to reference it in your views with:

`#{stockOrderBean.orderReport}`

So your table definition should look like:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{stockOrderBean.orderReport}" var="order"..>
```

You need to make sure that your list contains objects of the same class/superclass and not completely different objects to make it work. Then if your class `Order` has an attribute date with getter and setter, you can reference it in your table column with:

```
 <h:outputText value="#{order.date}"/>
```

Comment: but i want to display fields from two different classes - some fields from OrderStock and some fields from TradeStock which are joined by common field called 'OrderID'.. Is this possible?? If not then what can be the alternative solution??

Comment: Do they have a common superclass or is the one the superclass of the other?

Comment: No they don't have a common superclass. OrderStock is the superclass of TradeStock..

Comment: Then you should type your arraylist as ArrayList<OrderStock> and can reference all propertise of the superclass in your dataTable.

Comment: Thanks.but can u please refer to my jpql query in my question. Your answer holds true if both o and t are returned. but what if only o(OrderStock) is returned?(OrderID is reference column in TradeStock)